# Can't get data from JSON file after modifying it

Tags: php, json, class, oop

I created a class that is responsible for getting and modifying data in a JSON file. After using the method for adding data, the method for getting data returns null.

JSON represents an object with two fields: "the last id" - number, and "posts" - the array of posts (associative arrays that contain strings). The method "getPosts()" must return the array of posts,  the method "addPost($post)" must add a new post to the array.

The problem appears in this scenario:

1. I use getPosts(), it works just fine.
2. I use addPost(), it adds new post to the JSON.
3. If after that I use getPosts() again it returns null.

If I will run script again without using addPost(), getPosts() would return an updated array. Why addPost() affects the result of getPosts()?

```
class PostStorage {
    private $path;

    public function __construct($path) {
        $this->path = $path;
        if (file_exists($path)) return;

        $contents = array(
            "last_id" => 0,
            "posts" => array()
        );
        $this->setStorage($contents);
    }

    public function getPosts() {
        return $this->getStorage()['posts'];
    }

    public function addPost($post) {
        $storage = $this->getStorage();
        $newId = $storage['last_id'] + 1;
        $post['id'] = $newId;

        $storage['posts'][] = $post;
        $storage['last_id'] = $newId;
        $this->setStorage($storage);
    }

    private function setStorage($contents) {
        $handler = fopen($this->path, 'w');
        fwrite($handler, json_encode($contents));
        fclose($handler);
    }

    private function getStorage() {
        $handler = fopen($this->path, 'r');
        $contents = fread($handler, filesize($this->path));
        fclose($handler);
        return json_decode($contents, TRUE);
    }
}

$postStorage = new PostStorage(JSON_PATH);

$post = array(
    "title" => "some title",
    "content" => "some content"
);

echo(json_encode($postStorage->getPosts())); // is fine
$postStorage->addPost($post); // file was modified
echo(json_encode($postStorage->getPosts())); // now it returns null
```

Comment: `$postStorage->addPost($post);` Where is `$post` set?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't added initialization of $post in the code, but now it's here. This line was in the original script as well.

Comment: @kerbholz Sorry I didn't change it earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of calls to `filesize` are cached. Because of this the second call to `filesize` in `getStorage` returns the old size. Because of this only a part of the file is returned: `{"last_id":1,"posts":[{`. This causes the json parser to fail and return an empty array. This array doesn't have the `posts` key and thus returns null in `getPosts`.

The solution is to call `clearstatcache();` before calling `filesize`.
Example code:

```
  private function getStorage() {
        clearstatcache();
        $handler = fopen($this->path, 'r');
        $contents = fread($handler, filesize($this->path));
        fclose($handler);

        return json_decode($contents, TRUE);
    }
```

More information about this caching "feature": https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php